# Table View not populating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I know this is an oft-asked question/problem. I've looked through a bunch of Q&A for my problem, but I guess I'm a little thick, because I didn't see an answer anywhere.

I have a file with in an array that I would like to use to populate a tableView.

The problem is that it's not being called. Neither is numberOfRowsInSection or numberOfSectionsInTableView. I far as I can see, only viewDidLoad was called.

I have 1 section, the number of elements in my array equals 3 (as opposed to nil).

Relevant code is here...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FileControl *fileArray = [[FileControl alloc] init];
    matArray = [fileArray findUniqueItemsInArray:0 :[fileArray setFileToArray]];
    [fileArray release];
    NSLog(@"%i \n %@", [matArray count], matArray); // matArray is filled.
    NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad"); }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSLog(@"CellForRowAtIndexPath");

    NSString *text = [matArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:text];

    return cell; }

@interface MaterialTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    IBOutlet UITableView *materialTableView;
    NSArray *matArray;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *matArray;

@end
```

The other methods are standard.

I guess my problem lies in that I don't completely understand the flow well enough.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does calling `[tableView reloadData];` from the `viewDidLoad` method cause the table view to update?

Comment: matArray is of type NSArray ; You are allocating a FileControl type to NSArray ? Try changing either of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set your UIViewController subclass to be the [`delegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [`dataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) of the UITableView in question? Without doing so, none of the methods you mention will be called.

Comment: I just added the header file code. Is the (now) above what you mean? If so, then that existed during my problem.

Comment: @GaleDragon, almost. That code simply declares that you implement the appropriate protocols. It does not actually link any specific UITableView to your controller. If you're using a .xib file, you need to drag connections from the delegate and datasource outlets of the UITableView to the File's Owner. In code, you could also just say something like self.tableView.delegate = self; and self.tableView.datasource = self;

Comment: Okay, I connected them up, but then `-[UIApplication tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b109b0` appears in `main`. What does that mean?

Comment: It looks like you aren't setting the correct object to be the delegate and dataSource. My guess is that you are using the MainWindow.xib to put the UITableView on there. If I was right about the MainWindow.xib, make sure the connections are NOT going to File's Owner, which for that xib file is UIApplication.

Comment: Hmm, are you setting this up the main window .xib, where the File's Owner is actually UIApplication, and not an instance of a custom UIViewController subclass?

Comment: Yeah, that's me. I was following this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw&feature=related but when the time came for the tableview to be populated, nothing happened.

Comment: Holy crap. I don't know what I did (well, I do, but I wasn't expecting much) but it's running through 'number of sections' and 'number of rows' now. Apparently, I one connection missing in the .xib file. *facepalm*

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using a `UITableViewController`.

If you are using `UITableView` it is a little bit more complicated (in this case you need to implement `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource` protocols). 
[update] This is not your case, you are using `UITableViewController`.

Add this line to the end of your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Or move this:

```
FileControl *fileArray = [[FileControl alloc] init];
matArray = [fileArray findUniqueItemsInArray:0 :[fileArray setFileToArray]];
[fileArray release];
```

to the `init` method. Your `init` method should look like this:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style])) {
        FileControl *fileArray = [[FileControl alloc] init];
        matArray = [fileArray findUniqueItemsInArray:0 :[fileArray setFileToArray]];
        [fileArray release];
        NSLog(@"%i \n %@", [matArray count], matArray); // matArray is filled.
        NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad");
    }
    return self;
}
```

If you do not see any message in the log, it means that you are not using that method to initialize your object.

Please show all your code in the .m and .h files.

Comment: Huh. I did move the `FileControl` section to the `init` method (and by that I took to be `initWithStyle`), along with an NSLog(). It seems even that isn't being called. What's going on here?

Comment: @GaleDragon You need to make sure you are using that method (initWithStyle) to initialize your object.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion. Just give a shot for a test. In the - (void)viewDidLoad declare this.

instead of : `matArray = [fileArray findUniqueItemsInArray:0 :[fileArray setFileToArray]];`

Use this: `matArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileArray findUniqueItemsInArray:0 :[fileArray setFileToArray]]];`

Comment: That didn't do much. Thanks though!

Comment: What would you get if you NSLog this: matArray in this method?`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 0):

Did you use

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return [self.matArray count];
}
```

Comment: Well, I changed it to that, but I didn't notice a change. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have added your tableview delegate to your .h file as shown below.

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {

}
```

Also make sure that you have connected your datasource and delegate in interface builder.
Do this by doing:

1. double click on your .xib file so it opens in interface builder.
2. left click on your tableview just once so its highlighted blue
3. right click on your tableview now and a menu should pop up.
4. drag the datasource & delegate to the files owner box.
5. make sure to save changes while in interface builder.

This should "connect" all the pieces needed to get it to work.

Happy Coding!!